# Android Wear: Disable (only) 'shake' gesture

Tags: android, wear-os, gesture

I have made an android wear extension that utilizes the (accessible) wrist gestures from the android wear API, as described here: https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/gestures.html

However, after letting a few people try the app, I noticed that when a flick inwards or outwards didn't work, they tend to flick their wrist twice or quickly back and forth. This triggers the 'standard' 'shake' wrist gesture, which cancels my android wear app completely.

**Question: does anyone know how to disable (or en-able for that matter) a specific wrist gesture?**

I have coded an alternative, that looks at your wrist rotation using the SENS_ROTATION_VECTOR, which works pretty well. However, this method is susceptible to other 'daily movements'. The build in wrist gesture is more stable and less vulnerable for 'daily movements'. I'd therefore prefer to use the standard wrist gestures.

I am running on android wear 1.0 (intended). I am looking forward to any help!

Comment: [`WearableListView`](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/gestures.html#using_wlv) has predefined actions for occurrences of wrist gestures when the View has the focus. Even if you use a `WearableListView`, you may want to use constants from the `KeyEvent` class. The predefined actions can be overridden by subclassing the `WearableListView` and re-implementing the `onKeyDown()` callback. The behavior can be disabled entirely by using `setEnableGestureNavigation(false)`. You may also check this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-wear/nhG_3g6nmRM).

Comment: @abielita, yes, though unfortunatly I am unable to influence the 'shake' gesture, as you describe from https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/gestures.html it also states it is unavailable for developers. I therefore either want to only enable the flick in/out or only disable the shake gesture. Any thoughts?